# Is there a way i can make sure my html page always doesn't scroll up (ie window.scrollTo(0,0)) on page reload using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution where my page should not scroll to the top always after my page reload.

Like for ex: I'm in a product listing page in my website and i select some filter because of which page reloads and on page load page scrolls to the top.

Is there a way i can stop page scrolling to top on page load.

One solution i can think of is to read the current scroll position and set the scroll position on page reload.

Is there any other solution using javascript, so that i avoid this behaviour.

Comment: *read the current scroll position and set the scroll position on page reload.* It is the way that i use and i think is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your filtered data with AJAX and append it to your page. You wouldn't need to worry about the scroll resetting when you leave the page, because you won't be leaving it at all. You are just going to add new data (or remove old one). That would probably require a rework on your code, though.

If you're interested in the AJAX soultion, you can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Thank you mate for the reply. In my scenario, i cannot go with AJAX as it involves lot of rework. I want to achieve this with post back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll precisely to the last scroll position before page reload, I think the only solution is to store `window.pageYOffset` in something like local/session storage.

If you just want to scroll to the top of the product list, you can do something like this :

```js
const productsList = document.querySelector(".js-products-list");
const productsListOffsetTop = productsList.offsetTop;

window.scrollTo(0, productsListOffsetTop);
```

```html
<div class="ProductsList js-products-list">
  <!-- the products -->
</div>
```

In Chrome, I had a little issue with this code. I had to put `window.scrollTo(...)` in a `setTimeout()`

You can also consider refreshing the products list with an XHR call when the user updates the filters.